# Ordering some data with information from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, relationship

there are other questions just like mine here, but none of them actually work for me.

I have a Rails project, with 3 models: Unity, City, State, which have their relationships as below:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :unities
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cities
end

class Unity < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :state, through: :city
end
```

I wish I could be able to order my unities with respect to their city.name or state.name, as well as to order the cities according to their state.name. But I just can't figure it out. I tried, for example, `City.all.joins(:state).order('state.id')` as suggested in some question here at StackOverflow, but it gives me `missing FROM clause entry for 'city'`. How could I make it?

Comment: Your error is misleading. Did you get that error while doing `City.all.joins(:state).order('state.id')`?

Comment: `belongs_to :state, through: :city` just note that `through` is not an option for a `belongs_to` association

Comment: The statement in your example alone would never raise an SQL error (**except when you run it in console**). Perhaps you can clarify exactly what error you get when you run exactly what statement. Presenting the returned string of `City.all.joins(:state).order('state.id').explain` would help.

Comment: It should be 'states.id' instead of 'state.id'. Order clause expects table name not the association name

Comment: @AkshayGoyal, if you could write it as a real answer, I can mark it as accepted, cause it was just this, really thanks

Comment: I am glad i could help. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `order('states.id')` instead of `order('state.id')`. Order clause expects table name not the association name.